# Can I make mutt automatically sync after reading an email?

Tags: mutt

I get notifications of new email when there are files in my maildir directories `~/.mail/*/Inbox/new`. However, when I read a new email in `mutt`, files only move out of these directories when I quit `mutt`, or sync the mailbox. Ideally, I'd like the email to move immediately, when read. Hence I attempted to modify the default commands associated with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (in index), and <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> (in pager), by adding the following to `~/.mutt/muttrc`.

```
macro index <Enter> "<display-message><sync-mailbox>" "display a message, then sync"
macro pager j "<next-undeleted><sync-mailbox>" "move to the next undeleted message, then sync"
macro pager k "<previous-undeleted><sync-mailbox>" "move to the previous undeleted message, then sync"
```

I confirmed that these were accepted by `mutt` by pressing <kbd>?</kbd> for help in index/pager. <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> seem to work fine in pager mode; sync is immediately run. However, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in index mode doesn't seem to work; there is no sync. FWIW I tried to sync manually by pressing <kbd>$</kbd> after <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and this worked correctly, moving the files as expected.

How can I make <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately sync after displaying the message?

## Edit

My <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> hacks don't work perfectly either. If I search using `notmuch-mutt`, it creates a temporary mailbox. After opening a mail in the pager, then pressing <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>, the next email is selected, but the pager is closed, presumably because `sync` fails. I get the error:

```
Mailbox is read-only.
```

So my question is now the more generic title: How can I make mutt automatically sync after reading an email?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you find an optimal solution?

Comment: @Maximko Unfortunately not.

Comment: Changing `<Enter>` to `<Return>` in `macro index <Enter>` seems to work. Opening a message in index then syncs the mailbox.